# Import data from different columns and paste in rows using google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I've this data, but my problem is to concatenate the information into lines, cause works on the way

First will the the COl A til COl D to filter where we have mismatches between A and D, but also take where on Col D has text. But I already build this part.

And do the same with the Col E til Col H.

```
     A       B  C   D            E      F   G   H
2020-04-30  BA  BU  fsdf    2020-04-30  G   X   
2020-04-30  BU  BA          2020-04-30  L   Z   
2020-04-29  BA  BU          2020-04-29  H   W   
2020-04-29  BU  BA          2020-04-29  G   Q   dfdf
2020-04-28  BA  BU  sdfsdfs 2020-04-28  L   W   dfdf
2020-04-28  AA  BA          2020-04-28  H   AA  
2020-04-25  AA  BA          2020-04-25  G   X   fd
2020-04-22  BU  BA  sdfsdfs 2020-04-22  L   Z   
2020-04-19  AA  BU          2020-04-19  H   W   d
2020-04-19  AA  BA          2020-04-19  G   Q   
2020-03-27  BA  AA  sdfsdf  2020-03-27  L   W   
2020-03-27  BA  AA          2020-03-27  H   AA  dfdf
2020-03-26  BU  AA          2020-03-26  G   X   
2020-03-18  BA  AA          2020-03-18  L   Z   
2020-03-18  AA  BU          2020-03-18  H   W
```

My problem is cause I want to the same from Col E til Col H but pasting below the previous information. I'd like to have on this way:

```
2020-04-30  BA  BU  fsdf
2020-04-28  BA  BU  sdfsdfs
2020-04-22  BU  BA  sdfsdfs
2020-03-27  BA  AA  sdfsdf
2020-04-29  G   Q   dfdf
2020-04-28  L   W   dfdf
2020-04-25  G   X   fd
2020-04-19  H   W   d
2020-03-27  H   AA  dfdf
```

I alreaby built the script in two ways but I cound't do on a way that I can concatenate or do something like that.

`=filter(importrange("xx","Database!$A:$D"),importrange("xx","Database!$B:$B")<>importrange("xx","Database!$C:$C"),istext(importrange("xx","Database!$D:$D")))`

`query(importrange("xx","Database!$A:$AA50"),"SELECT Col1,Col4 WHERE (Col2<>Col3 and Col4 is not null)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("xx", "Database!A:D"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("xx", "Database!E:H")},
 "select Col1,Col4 
  where Col2<>Col3 
    and Col4 is not null", 0)
```